# Regular expression for selecting text inside <td></td>

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

What would be the best regular expression to extract only text from  tags? If I have for example this kind of html markup

```
<tr class="classo">
<td>text1</td>
<td class="dot">text2 </td>
<td>text3</td>
<td class="dot"> text4</td>
<td class="dot">text4</td>
</tr>
```

Number of td tags is not fixed, also some of them will have class attribute, but I'm only interesting in getting the text from inside td tag

Comment: What do you mean by extract; do you want the text between the td tags to be stored as a javascript variable? Or do you want to change the text within the tags?

Comment: To parse HTML, it's generally better to use an established library (such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ) than putting together custom regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of spending time with regular expressions, use something designed for the task.  I like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> s = """
... <tr class="classo">
... <td>text1</td>
... <td class="dot">text2 </td>
... <td>text3</td>
... <td class="dot"> text4</td>
... <td class="dot">text4</td>
... </tr>
... """
>>> 
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.find_all("td")
[<td>text1</td>, <td class="dot">text2 </td>, <td>text3</td>, <td class="dot"> text4</td>, <td class="dot">text4</td>]
>>> [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all("td")]
[u'text1', u'text2 ', u'text3', u' text4', u'text4']
```

Comment: I actually have table row in BeautifulSoup selected, but I want to extract content from <td></td> row by row, so I can place it in a dictionary and have something like this rowDict = {'row1': ['text1','text2', 'text3'], 'row2': ['text1', 'text2','text3...']}

Comment: A) if you had additional requirements, edit the original question to include them. B) if your keys really are nothing more than "row1", "row2", etc., then just use a list of lists and get each row's data as `rowData[0]`, `rowData[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>` will properly do.

But may I recommend you to use the [HTMLParser Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Took me the time to write you another example using the HTMLParser:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class TDExtractor(HTMLParser):

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
      if tag == 'td':
          self.recording = True

  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
      if tag == 'td':
          self.recording = False

  def handle_data(self, data):
      if self.recording:
          self.data.append(data)

  def reset(self):
      HTMLParser.reset(self)
      self.data = []
      self.recording = False
```

And in action:

```
> tdextractor = TDExtractor()
> tdextractor.feed(some_htmldata)
> print(tdextractor.data) # will print a list with all the td data.
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions were not designed to parse HTML. HTML is not a regular language and cannot be parsed very easily with regular expressions.

A lot of people like `BeautifulSoup`, but it is pretty [slow](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2010/08/16/beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-performance/) ([another source](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/)) and not as good as `lxml`, which can even use `BeautifulSoup` as a parser as needed.

Here's a solution using `lxml`.

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> html = lxml.html.fromstring("""
... <tr class="classo">
... <td>text1</td>
... <td class="dot">text2 </td>
... <td>text3</td>
... <td class="dot"> text4</td>
... <td class="dot">text4</td>
... </tr>""")
>>> print [e.text for e in html.xpath("td")]
['text1', 'text2 ', 'text3', ' text4', 'text4']
```